# Source code was not found for file:///android_asset/... when encountering cordova errors

Tags: cordova, sentry

I am tracking client side errors using [sentry](https://sentry.io) for my cordova app.

The error reporting is not perfect (different errors get mapped together), but I at least get some sort of stack trace for all kinds of devices.

I noticed, that some errors come together with further `file not found` errors for files that are shipped with the app:
[image]

Has anyone experienced this as well? These files do exist. Are the `not found` errors some result of the initial error? Or is it the other way around? Or is part of the sentry bug which lumps all those errors together? (marking new errors as "regression" etc.)

I have a setup where I wait for both `onDeviceReady` and `window.onload` events to register before executing any code. This should result in all assets to be properly loaded. Or is there a problem with that approach? Are there other cases which might cause assets to partially load only?

Also this is the original error reported:
[image]
I just noticed, that the error occurred in one of the files which were apparently not found.

Comment: Are you using the official SDK? https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-cordova

Comment: No, I simply included `https://cdn.ravenjs.com/3.17.0/raven.min.js` and used their setup.

Comment: Please use the official SDK, there are many little nits to it on configuring everything correctly.

Comment: I tried and unfortunately ran into several issues with the wizard (see issue #7320).